# Using Google Analytics to view product hits

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics but fairly new to it.

I have a list of products on my site, they have the following URL:

- `example.com/product/1`
- `example.com/product/2`

In Google Analytics, how can I view which product has the most hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of hits on each URL is available from:

Behavior → Site Content → All Pages

Once you are there there is a search box where you can filter for only URLs that match a pattern.  For example you could put "product" into that search box to get a report of just your product URLs.

[image: Google Analytics filter URL report]